# Getting input from html in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

so I figured out how to make the code work but I don't understand why it works this way

```js
var notaEx = document.getElementById("nota-ex").value;
    
function calculate () {
  console.log(notaEx);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nota-ex"/>
<button onclick="calculate();">Button</button>
```

Working version

```js
var notaEx = document.getElementById("nota-ex");

function calculate () {
  console.log(notaEx.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nota-ex"/>
<button onclick="calculate();">Button</butto>
```

can someone explain why the second version works but the first does not ?

Comment: Is `calculeaza` a typo, or are the functions actually called different things? (Also, think about the when things are called, and when you're getting the value)

Comment: Assuming you forgot to change `calculeaza`... because when the var is defined, `#nota-ex` does not have a value. When the button is clicked, presumably  it does.

Comment: it's a mistake from me, the function is called calculate and even after i replaced it still does not work

Comment: Oh, I got it why it does not work, thank you

Answer (score 0):

let me explain

```
 <button onclick="calculate();"></button>
```

see your html code you are asking it to fetch a function named calculate
but in your js first version function is named as calculeaza

```
function calculeaza () {
   console.log(notaEx);
}
```

therefore when you click the button it does not work 
while on secound version function name match the function name defined 
in button

```
 function calculate () {
   console.log(notaEx);
 }
```

Comment: Read the comments. Even after changing the function name it won't work.

Comment: It does not work because the var is declared before the function (in the first example)